# C - Hashing Struct with n amount of unsigned int properties

Tags: c, hash, integer

I have a struct:

```
struct A
{
    unsigned int a, b, c, d, ...    
}
```

I want to make a function:

```
unsigned int A_hash(const A* const var)
{

    return ...  
}
```

The number returned needs to be very very large as modulus for HashTable insertion will not work properly if `A_hash(var) < myHashTable.capacity`.

I've seen questions like this before like *"Hash function that takes in two integers", "hash function that takes in five integers", etc* but what about`n` integers? I'm looking for a more general algorithm for *decent* hashing. It doesn't need to be enterprise-level.

I was thinking perhaps start with a massive number like

`return (0x7FFFFFFFF & a) + (0x7FFFFFFFF & b) + ...`

but I don't think this will be good enough. I also don't know how to stop the `A_hash` function from overflowing but that may be another problem all together.

Comment: treat your struct as a contiguous array of bytes and used Adler-32 or some other rolling checksum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think implicitly you are asking how it is possible to treat the entire object just like a long byte-stream, like @bruceg explained. If I'm wrong, then you might as well ignore this answer, because this is what I will address. Note that this solution does not apply merely for hashing, but for anything that requires you to treat data like bytes (such as copying from/writing to memory or files).

I think what you are looking for is merely reading byte by byte. For this you can insipre yourself from [`std::ostream::write`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/) (which is a C++ method though). For example, you could write `A_hash` in such a way that you could invoke it like this :

```
int hash = A_hash((char*)&a, sizeof(a)); // where 'a' is of type 'struct A'.
```

You could write `A_hash`, for example, like this:

```
unsigned int A_hash(char* data, unsigned int dataSize)
{
    unsigned int hash = someValue;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dataSize; ++i)
    {
        char byte = data[i];
        doSomethingWith(hash);
    }

    return hash;

}
```

The great advantage of this method is that you don't need to rewrite the function if you add/remove fields to your struct ; `sizeof(A)` will expand/reduce at compile-time. The other great advantage is that it works for any value, so you can reuse that function with any type you want, including `int`, another `struct`, an `enum`, a pointer, ...